# Decimal Conversion F# Script vs. Compiled F#

Tags: f#, decimal, type-conversion

In the F# Interactive, the following piece of code works:

```
> printfn "%A" (decimal 1I)
1M
```

However, in a compiled F# program, an error message appears:

```
The type 'Numerics.BigInteger' does not support a conversion to the type 'decimal'
```

What happened there? Is it because the different set of references (and versions of references) are used between F# versions? or the internal representations of the `decimal` are different across compiled and interpreted modes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is likely because your F# compiled program is targeting the .NET Framework 2.0 / F# 2.0. The F# interactive is using .NET Framework 4.0 / F# 4.0.

The 2.0 Framework uses the `BigInteger` in FSharp.Core. The 4.0 Framework uses `System.Numerics.BigInteger`. The FSharp.Core one does not have the conversion to decimal.

Change your project to target .NET 4.0 and add a reference to System.Numerics and everything should match up.

Comment: +1 You beat me to it. I'll leave my answer there, in case some of the additional details were useful.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that there is some inconsistency in whether `BigInteger` can be converted using the `decimal` function or not. It seems to depend on the version of .NET that you're compiling for. If you're using the F# compiler (or F# interactive) from Visual Studio 2010, then the default target is .NET 4.0. For that target, the compilation works fine:

```
C:\Temp>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\Fsc.exe" test.fs
Microsoft (R) F# 3.0 Compiler build 2.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
```

You can change the target framework by explicitly referencing .NET 2.0 version of `mscorlib.dll` and `FSharp.Core.dll`. Then the compiler reports the error you described:

```
C:\Temp>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\Fsc.exe" test.fs --noframework 
  -r:C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharp-2.0.0.0\bin\FSharp.Core.dll 
  -r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
Microsoft (R) F# 3.0 Compiler build 2.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

test.fs(1,23): error FS0001: The type 'System.Numerics.BigInteger' does not support 
  a conversion to the type 'decimal'
```

If you're getting the error when compiling the project, then your project is probably configured to compile for .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

**Same result**

```
Microsoft(R) F# 2.0 Interactive ビルド 4.0.40219.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
> printfn "%A" (decimal 1I);;
1M
val it : unit = ()

>fsc test.fs
Microsoft(R) F# 2.0 Compiler ビルド 4.0.40219.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

>test
1M
```